# Kotlin, теряется параметр при передаче в конструктор предка

Tags: наследование, kotlin

Есть исходный абстрактный класс

```
abstract class GrandDad(val params:Array<Any>) {
    ...
}
```

От него наследует другой абстрактный класс

```
abstract class Dad(params: Array<Any> = arrayOf()) : GrandDad(params) {
    ...
}
```

А уже от него наследует обычный класс

```
class Son(param:String) : Dad(arrayOf(param)) {
    ....
}
```

И вот когда я делаю так:

```
val son = Son("test")
```

То в `val params:Array<Any>` оказывается пустой массив. Т.е. похоже на то, что параметр теряется при передачи от `Son` к `Dad`

Уже весь мозг сломал. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, это баг в компиляторе. Он должен запрещать передачу `Array<String>` в качестве `Array<Any>`, потому что массивы в Kotlin, в отличие от Java, [инвариантны](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays) (типы массивов не являются подтипами друг друга, даже если их типы-аргументы являются).

Но компилятор не запрещает такой вызов суперконструктора, а вместо этого генерирует некорректный код (например, если убрать значение по умолчанию у `params: Array<Any> = arrayOf()`, то программа упадёт в рантайме с `NoSuchMethodError`).

Я оставил отчёт об ошибке: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19435

Спасибо за внимательность к мелочам!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так всегда, мучаешься, страдаешь, делишься своей болью с кем-то и ответ приходит сам собой...

```
class Son(param:String) : Dad(arrayOf(param))
```

Тут конструкция `arrayOf(param)` превращается в `Array<String>`, а у класса `Dad` есть только конструктор для `Array<Any>` и (**!!!!**) для конструктора без параметров, который по умолчанию приводит `param = arrayOf()`

Т.е.

```
Dad(params: Array<Any> = arrayOf())
```

Это по сути два конструктора

```
construncot(params: Array<Any>):super(params)
construncot():this(arrayOf())
```

Доказать не могу, но похоже, что при передаче массива отличного от `Array<Any>` по тихому вызывается второй конструктор.

В общем вот так отлично работает:

```
class Son(param:String) : Dad(arrayOf(param as Any))
```

Comment: По идее должно быть нельзя `Array<String>` передать в качестве `Array<Any>`, потому что массивы в Kotlin, в отличие от Java, инвариантны. Всё остальное похоже на баг. Сейчас поищу, нет ли такой известной проблемы, и если нет, напишу репорт.

Comment: Зарепортил: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19435

Comment: Вы почти угадали. Здесь все дело в очередности вызовов инициализаторов. Чтобы лучше понять в чем дело прочтите эту статью https://medium.com/keepsafe-engineering/an-in-depth-look-at-kotlins-initializers-a0420fcbf546

Comment: @ArnisShaykh  а как связан порядок инициализации с выбором неверного конструктора?\